# How could two circles be connected when one has an interrupted edge ring?

Tags: modeling, edges

I created a membrane of one speaker and want to connect a duplicate, the outer edge ring is interrupted (because I used *Knife Project* to cut the holes in the case). The problem is that *Grid Fill* expects a closed loop and *Bridge Edge Loops* creates this:

[image]

Is there another way than connecting them manually?

[.blend](http://pasteall.org/blend/30619)

Comment: Based on Gandalf3s answer, I would recommend either re doing your speaker, or at least giving it a major topology overhaul.

Comment: @GiantCowFilms I don't agree, as far as I can tell it should be fixable in a couple steps (see gif in my answer)..

Comment: @gandalf3 You may be right in this case, but their may be other issues. Also, It is much better to learn to not mess up rather than how to fix something that is messed up. In this case though, you are right and fixing will probably be the best idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually because you have a mis-matched vertex count, most likely because of a mirroring error:

[image]

You also seem to have a duplicate of the speaker:

[image]

To fix this:

[image]

1. Select a vertex on the speaker and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> to select connected geometry, then press <kbd>Delete</kbd>*> vertices* to delete it.
2. Select the extra loops on the sides and delete them with <kbd>Delete</kbd> *> Edge loops*
3. Bridge edge loops now works as expected.

Comment: Thanks, next time I should check first for dups, wonder how that happend again.